# C++ Linked List Move Assignment and Move Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, nodes

I have am writing an implementation of a singly linked list for my Object Oriented Programming class. In the program, I have written a class called `Polynomial` which implements the linked list and allows me to modify it. The Nodes in the linked list contain two fields: a term and a pointer to the next node. The term is a struct that contains two fields: a coefficient and an exponent.

I have implemented the class and its methods correctly up to this point, but I am coming to a problem in the project that I need help with. One of the requirements is that we implement a Move Assignment (?) and a Move Constructor. Unfortunately our teacher did not go into good detail on what these are or how to implement them, and now I am completely lost. I already implemented a Copy Assignment and a Copy Constructor, but I do not know how to implement the Move Assignment and Move Constrcutor.

Here is the class:

```
class Polynomial {
        Node* Head;
        int size = 0;
    public:
        Polynomial(); // default constructor
        Polynomial(const Polynomial& v); // copy constructor
        ~Polynomial();
        void addTerm(Term term);
        unsigned int degree() const;
        double coefficientFor(unsigned int exponent) const;
        void clear();

        // Copy Assignment Operator
        Polynomial& operator=(const Polynomial& rhs);

    private:
        void DeleteInvalidNode();
    };
```

Is there any way that someone can help me with this implementation and what its purpose is?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to *copy* a polynomial from one place to another.  For instance, you might want to write a method that lets us take a polynomial to some power.  (Assume you already wrote an overload of the multiplication operator).  That might look like this [1]

```
Polynomial Polynomial::pow(int n) const
{
  Polynomial result = *this; // copy constructor

  for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) { result = result * *this; }

  return result; 
}
```

It's important that you make a *copy* of `*this` when you assign it to `result` in the first line, because otherwise you might be modifying `*this` when you're trying to modify `result`.

On the other hand, let's say that you later use this method as follows [2]:

```
Polynomial s;

// ...

s = p.pow(3); // move-assignment
```

The result of `p.pow(3)` is a polynomial, but there's no need to preserve `s` and `p.pow(3)` as separate objects here because we have no way of referencing the object referred to as `p.pow(3)` at any further point in the code.

Consequently, we don't need to be careful about making a copy here; if there's some way that we can transfer the object returned by `p.pow(3)` without carefully copying every piece of it then we're fine.

We declare this method like so:

```
class Polynomial
{
  // ...

  /** Move constructor */
  Polynomial(Polynomial &&);

  /** Move-assignment operator */
  Polynomial& operator=(Polynomial &&);

};
```

In this case, since your polynomial is represented by a linked list, it's enough to copy the `Head` pointer over, and then do whatever you need to to the object you're moving to make sure that its destructor doesn't destroy the linked list nodes.  That would depend on how you wrote everything, but probably you can get away with something like setting the `Head` pointer of the thing you've moved to `nullptr`.

(Of course remember when writing an assignment operator to clean up anything that needs cleanup on the LHS!)

After you move-construct or move-assign from something, the object you moved from is allowed to be left in a condition where none of its functionality necessarily works except for the destructor; it's not meant to be used any further.  For instance in the example above where `s = p.pow(3)`, if polynomials have a move-assignment operator then this will be called to move the return value into `s`, and then the destructor will be called on the return value.

---

[1] This is actually not the best way to write this method, but it gives me a quick and somewhat relevant example so I'm going to run with it.

[2] There's a little subtlety here, explaining why I wrote this as two separate lines.  If I were to write `Polynomial s = p.pow(3)` it would actually bypass all of this via *copy elision*, basically telling `Polynomial::pow` to use `s` as its return value directly.  Copy- and move-assignment are only really used if you're assigning to something that previously had a different value.